# Beautiful MapServer maps and their map files

Tags: cartography, mapserver

Looking for

beautiful MapServer produced maps

and

*their associated map files* to get insights from it.

*beautiful* is subjective,

quick definition: pleasant to look at such as maps from http://mapbox.com/maps/

Any ideas where to get them ?